# Realm Swift subquery return all parent with specific childs

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have two RLMObject and I created one to many relationship. I want to run join query on that so it should return all categories and each category contain paid items only.

```
class Category: Object {
    dynamic var title = ""
    let items = List<Item>()
}

class Item: Object {
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var cost = 0.0
    dynamic var isPaid = false
    dynamic var category: Category?
}
```

I use this code but it still return all categories and all items including not paid items

```
let categories = realm.objects(Category.self).filter("ANY items.isPaid = %@", true)
```

I believe the cause is if one/many items in a category have isPaid = true, this category will be added into Results<>. What I want to achive is like in the example below

Lets say in database i have

```
category[0] has item[0].isPaid = true, item[1].isPaid = false
category[1] has item[0].isPaid = true, item[1].isPaid = true
```

I want the Results<> should contain

```
category[0] has item[0].isPaid = true
category[1] has item[0].isPaid = true, item[1].isPaid = true
```

Comment: That's odd. I just tested this and it was working fine. Have you tried potentially just making `true` inline in the query? (i.e. `"ANY items.isPaid = true"` )

Comment: Sorry I update the description and hope you can help.

Comment: Ahh, I don't think that's possible. The `filter` query will let you get any objects that have at least one child object where `isPaid` is true, but you'll need to then manually iterate through each `category` object to retrieve only the `isPaid = true` child objects.